# 1960's Batman and Superman?

Tags: dc, batman, tv, superman, batman-1966

Has there ever been a team-up of Batman from the 1960's tv series with a superman of the same period? I don't think it ever happened in the tv series, but say in a comic or cartoon, even if it's a recent comic/cartoon but obviously intended to be the same universe as the original tv series?

Comment: There have never been comics made of those series specifically, but the comics of the era reflected the same values as the shows did.  'Canon' at the time was fast and loose, and there were no 'multiple universes', though sometimes they went to 'a different universe' to tell a specific story.  In short, you won't find a better answer than Richard's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superman and Batman "crossed over" almost as soon as they were in print. Superman debuted in 1938 and the first Batman/Superman co-venture was in 1940 albeit in separate stories in the same issue.

[image]

The first "shared story" was in 1952 in Superman #76 in a story entitled '[The Mightiest Team in the World](http://www.comicvine.com/superman-76-the-mightiest-team-on-earth/4000-120155/)' where Superman and Batman are forced to share a cabin on a cruise liner.

[image]

There were numerous shared story comics in the 1960s (embodying many of the traits of the TV Batman and Superman) including "[The Composite Superman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_Superman)!" in which both characters are literally combined by a freak accident and "[The Sons of Superman and Batman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Sons)" set in an alternate universe in which both characters have children.

[image]

You can find a wealth of covers and additional info [here](http://www.vulture.com/2013/07/history-batman-and-superman-through-the-years.html).

Per Sumbuddy's comment below, I've investigated the Annuals that were published while the TV series was on the air and found this. It appears to be a crossover between Superman and Batman with batman modelled on the 1966 TV series.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't think that answers my question. I'm specifically asking about the universe of the tv series (we'll call that Earth-60) and not the mainstream DCU or Earth-1.

Comment: @sumbuddyx You should edit that clarification into the question.

Comment: @sumbuddyx - Since there hasn't been a batman or superman comic based on the 1960s series' the answer is a straight "no" to your question

Comment: This is what sparked my idea. http://www.comicbooktherapy.com/dc-launching-a-new-batman-comic-based-on-the-1960s-tv-show-113350. It's called Batman '66. so i guess I was thinking there might have been some reference or say some kind of story in maybe an annual where they might show the adam west batman with a similar superman of that period (george reeve superman!!). however thinking upon your answer richard i can see why that wouldn't happen as until recently there wouldn't be nostalgia for that particular version of the character to make it sale worthy. i shall upvote accordingly. cheers :)

Comment: Ooh. That's actually a pretty good point. I'll investigate the annuals.

Comment: @sumbuddyx - I've found you a direct crossover from 1969, with Superman and a Batman modelled on the TV series; http://static1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110417184653/marvel_dc/images/b/bc/Superman_Annual_1969.jpg

Comment: wow!! thanks for that!